# Added if else argument and lost variable from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","clarks");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$place = $_GET['place'];
$place2 = $_GET['place2'];
$return = $_GET['return'];
$people = $_GET['people'];
$pickup = $_GET['pickup'];
$dropoff = $_GET['dropoff'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pricelist WHERE place1='$place' AND place2='$place2' AND people='$people'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if (!empty($row['Price']))
{
echo "Not Applicable";
}
else
{
  echo "<html><body style='background-color: #31ff01;'><link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>";
  echo "<div id='prices'>£";
  echo $row['Price'] * $return + $pickup + $dropoff;
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div id='back'>";
  echo "<a href='index.html'>Go Back</a>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<br>";
  }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is returning the "Not Applicable" from the if argument every time.

I've tried placing the lines in different order and using both the price and result variable, it still only returns not applicable but without the if else argument, the rest of it works as intended and brings up a price so I know the price variable shouldn't be empty and neither should the result variable.

With it returning not applicable all the time, I assume it's not retrieving the information from the database properly any more but I can't figure out why when it works perfectly fine without the if else.

Any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: PREPARE THE SQL INJECTION ATTACK!!

Comment: wrong condition brother..

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is wrong:

```
if (!empty($row['Price']))
    ^ here
{
echo "Not Applicable";
}
```

should be:

```
if (empty($row['Price']))
{
echo "Not Applicable";
}
```

You also have a serious sql injection problem, you should use prepared statements or at the very least use `mysqli`'s escaping function.

Comment: Thanks, this got the price up again, but if I input two places with no corresponding database row, I just get a blank page back, not the "Not applicable" that I want to show up. Also the sql injection stuff I'll look at later as I'm fairly new to coding so was just wanting to get it working first, thanks for the advice though, least I know what to search for now :)

Comment: @Steven You are already in the `while` loop and checking for an empty field in a found row. To check if there are any rows at all, you should count the number of rows outside the `while` loop, using for example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($row['Price']))
{
echo "Not Applicable";
}
else
{
  echo "<html><body style='background-color: #31ff01;'><link rel='stylesheet'  
.....
  }
 }
```

I think the in the if condition the negation causes the problem
Remove the exclamation mark!

Comment: Done this, as I commented above I get the prices back up now when it corresponds to places in the database, however when I enter values with no corresponding database row I get a blank page instead of the "Not applicable" I want to display.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are using mysqli_fetch_array instead of mysqli_fetch_assoc. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

You should also start using real_ escape_ string on your parameters, or do it in the right way with parameterized prepared statement. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","clarks");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$place = $_GET['place'];
$place2 = $_GET['place2'];
$return = $_GET['return'];
$people = $_GET['people'];
$pickup = $_GET['pickup'];
$dropoff = $_GET['dropoff'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pricelist WHERE place1='$place' AND place2='$place2' AND people='$people'");
$row = (mysqli_fetch_array($result));
$a = $row[3]; 

if (empty($a))
{
  echo "<html><body style='background-color: #31ff01;'><link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>";
  echo "<div id='prices'>";
  echo "N/A";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div id='back'>";
  echo "<a href='index.html'>Go Back</a>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<br>";
}
else
{
  echo "<html><body style='background-color: #31ff01;'><link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>";
  echo "<div id='prices'>£";
  echo $a * $return + $pickup + $dropoff;
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div id='back'>";
  echo "<a href='index.html'>Go Back</a>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<br>";
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Well I found this workaround, instead of using *while* I just got rid of it and assigned the price from the database into its own variable meaning there's no conflict with the *if else* statement. Works like a charm... now to look at prepared statements :S